# cycles material light changing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light

[image]I want a material where the side that is facing the light is glossy and the other side is some other shader like glass or something. What sort of nodes should I use? I've been searching around the internet for something related to this but I got nothing. I've actually been searching for many months but didn't realize I could just ask myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *Geometry* Node to control the Mix factor between two shaders in a *Mix Shader* node. Use the *Backfacing* socket to set one shader to the backface of the plane, and the other is set to the front face.[image: backfacing]

Comment: if im using a sphere it doesn't work

Comment: @SpaniardsFromheaven it does work, though the other material is only be visible from *inside* the sphere

Comment: Might want to edit your question to explain that then. I haven't an idea on that one, and a specific use case like that needs a specific answer.

Comment: In Texture Coordinate node, you can use the eyedropper to select your light object, and maybe then plugging 'Object' coordinate to mix factor might work.